# Auto hide sidebar when clicked outside of it

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I was using the below link to create a sidebar using angular animation and it works perfectly well.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidebar-animation?file=src%2Findex.html

But I want to add functionality to close the sidebar when user click outside the sidebar.

Comment: I think this may help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sidenav-experiments?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I ended up doing something like that but for the whole screen 
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidebar-animation-rqyiii?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
I added a directive `ClickOutsideDirective` that checks if clik is in or out menu

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) {

    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {

        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Genrally, side-bar or Drawer be used as a panel typically overlaid on top of a page and slides in from the side. User can interact with the side-bar or drawer without leaving the current page.

In your case though it is working almost, still there are few more things required. See below 'ant' angular component for such functionality which solves all of your issues and it is open-source.

**Ant Drawer:** https://ng.ant.design/components/drawer/en

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) for getting solution in jQuery.

If you don't want to use jQuery, based on the above post you can modify your code a little bit.

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="toggleMenu($event)" class="hamburger">
 <span>toggle menu</span>
</button>
<h1>{{name}} Sidebar</h1>

<app-menu [@slideInOut]="menuState" ></app-menu>
```

AppComponent Class of app.component.ts file:

```
export class AppComponent {
 name = "Angular";
 ngOnInit() {
  window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  this.menuState = this.menuState === 'in' ? 'out' : 'out';
 });
}
menuState: string = "out";

toggleMenu(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 this.menuState = this.menuState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
}
}
```

This should do the trick.